# System.Runtime.Cache not expiring?

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have implemented a solution in my ASP.NET project to automatically send some emails based on a time. I have done this by using the System.Runtime.Cache, specifically the CacheItemRemovedCallback. First of all i add the task to the cache in the Application_Start method:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    AddTask(reportElement.name, totalMinutes);
    ...
}
```

and the AddTask method then adds the item to the cache:

```
private void AddTask(string name, int minutes)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, minutes, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes),     Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}
```

So when the cache entry expires after the minutes specified in the AbsolutionExpiration, it calls my CacheItemRemoved method. This basically runs a report, sends an email and then re-adds the task to the cache, so it will run again after the time has expired again - simple. Here is part of the code we are concerned with in the CacheItemRemoved.

```
public void CacheItemRemoved(string taskName, object minutes, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    ...
    finally
    {
        AddTask(taskName, Convert.ToInt32(minutes));
    }
    ...
}
```

There is exception handling in the code, as you can see the re-adding of the task is in the finally block, so should always get called. And all the exception catch blocks do is log the error to the file, as i want to keep the task running even if the previous one fails.

This works perfectly on my local machine, but when on a Windows Server 2003, it basically just runs once. I have added extra debugging and it looks like the second time the cache entry is added, it simply doesn't expire. I am completely stuck now. The windows server is running IIS 6.0. Are there any settings for the cache i don't know about. Also, on the server it seems to expire at a completely different time to what was specified in the minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, minutes, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes),     Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
```

When you add your cache item why are you specifying CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, surely this will prevent the item from ever being removed (unless you run out of memory).

Comment: According to Microsoft: The cache items with this priority level will not be automatically deleted from the cache as the server frees system memory. However, items with this priority level are removed along with other items according to the item's absolute or sliding expiration time.